# How to obtain a reference to $table_prefix in $wpdb object

Tags: wpdb

I need to call the WordPress options table and pull some data. However, the table name may be different (typically wp_options) depending on whether the default table prefix was used on installation.

How can I obtain a reference to the site's table prefix in order to properly access the site's options table via $wpdb?

```
/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each a unique
 * prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
global $wpdb;
$prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
```

Comment: +1, I believe this is correct. I've since found that I need to call the options table with $wpdb->options rather than wp_options, which resolves my issue without needing the prefix.

Answer (score 0):

While you can get the prefix with `$wpdb->prefix`, as suggested by Pippin, you're much better off getting the table you need directly with `$wpdb->options` (in your case). `$wpdb` includes, by default, the table names for every table, accessible by `$wpdb->{table_name}`. For example: the posts table is `$wpdb->posts`...pretty straightforward stuff really.